# Angular Universal SSR on different platforms

Tags: angular, angular-cli, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

i have an Angular4 CLI project with Universal SSR. When I compile the universal server-part on my local machine (Windows) and try to run the universal bundle on an Ubuntu server, then i always get this error:

> ERROR {TypeError: Property '0' of undefined can not be read

My nodes and npm versions are:

local, windows:
Node v8.9.0
npm 5.5.1

Server, Ubuntu:
Node v8.6.0
npm 5.3.0
also tried with node v8.9.1 and npm 5.5.1

If i compile the universal server-part of my project on the Ubuntu server, then everything works fine and i can run the compiled universal-bundle without errors on the server.

But, i would like to get the local compiled universal package running on the Ubuntu server.
Is it possible to start a node app on a linux / ubuntu platform if the app was compiled on a windows machine?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the folders

> node_modules

on my local windows machine and on the ubuntu server and then reinstalled everything with

> npm install

Now the local compiled build also works on the linux server